# New with JavaFX and stuck

Tags: java, javafx

I'm learning Java(FX) but now, I'm at wit's end. I have an error which I don't understand. It should draw rectangles.

Error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/815033865.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3208)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
at cihly.Cihly.start(Cihly.java:22)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/84796442.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/584634336.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/873652227.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/501263526.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at
```

What should I do?

EDIT:

Here is my code:

Class1:

```
public class VyplnObrazovku {

private int zakladna;
private int sirkaCihly;
private int vyskaCihly;
private int sirkaProgramu = 600;
private int vyska;
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(600, 330);;
private GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();



private void nakresliCihlu(int x, int y, int vyska, int sirka) {

    gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    gc.fillRoundRect(x,y,sirka,vyska,5,5);
    gc.setFill(Color.RED);
    gc.fillRect(x+5, x+5, sirka-5, vyska-5);
}


public void rozmery(int vyska){
    this.zakladna = vyska;
    this.sirkaCihly = sirkaProgramu - 10 / zakladna;
    this.vyskaCihly = sirkaCihly / 2;
    this.vyska = vyska;
}

public void vypln(){
    int odecist = 0;
    int x = 5;
    int y = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < vyska; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < zakladna - odecist; j++){
            nakresliCihlu(x, y, this.vyskaCihly, this.sirkaCihly);
            x += sirkaCihly;
        }
        y += vyskaCihly;
        x = (int) (5 + (i*0.5));
        odecist++;
    }
}

private void drawShapes(GraphicsContext gc) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}


}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Cihly extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Controller:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label labelCislo;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    VyplnObrazovku plnic = new VyplnObrazovku();
    plnic.rozmery(5);
    plnic.vypln();
}    
}
```

EDIT2:

I was checking the FXMLDocument.fxml, but I cannot find any mistake. I would appreciate every advice.
FXMLDocument.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="320.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="cihly.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <Canvas height="330.0" layoutY="34.0" width="600.0" />
      <HBox layoutX="2.0" layoutY="6.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <Label prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="199.0" text="Zadejte výšku zdi v rozmezí 1 až 500:" />
            <TextField fx:id="labelCislo" />
            <Button fx:id="handleButtonAction" mnemonicParsing="false" text="OK" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: The error in "FXMLDocument.fxml", post that file.

Comment: My guess is that it is not finding the resource for the code  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml")); try to verify that the file location is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, in fxml file you have defined a `TextField` with `fx:id = labelCislo` but in controller class you are trying to inject this fx:id variable as `Label`. So the `FXMLLoader` cannot convert label to textfield. If you were posting the full exception error text, it would be more descriptive for us. However you truncated it...